# Multiple controllers in Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, joomla-3.3.x, mvc

I am totally Joomla noob and trying to figure out how to control MVC in Joomla. I've read [this](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_a_view_to_the_site_part) "Developing a MVC Component" in Joomla basic tutorial and understand that 
 the main controller is located under `components/com_component/controller.php` & other file is `components/com_helloworld/helloworld.php` which is pointing to `controller.php` file to execute the request. The question is, I want to create new `controller` folder and put all `controllers` in that folder like below. How to do that? 
[image: Controllers folder]

Any advise is really appreciated.
Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're confusing the purpose of your main / master controller (`controller.php`) and subcontrollers (everything in the `/controllers` folder). For more on this, see [the docs](https://docs.joomla.org/JController_and_its_subclass_usage_overview).

The main controller is typically used to do what you mention in your comment (render a view based on the `view` parameter, usually specified in the URL). In `controller.php`, the function that does this is called `display()`. So the following URL:

```
http://example.com/index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=test
```

Will result in calling the `display()` function in `controller.php` and loads the view `test` in `/views/test`.

Subcontrollers, in the `controllers` folder, are generally used for CRUD tasks, but can be called easily by using a `task` URL parameter. For example:

```
http://example.com/index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=test.process
```

Will result in calling the `process()` function in `/controllers/test.php` - notice the `task` parameter is `<controllerName>.<functionName>`

You'll see this used a lot to do actions that don't need a view, e.g in `com_content` to publish / checkin / checkout / delete articles (where the `task` is `article.publish` etc.,which means the controller at `controllers/article.php` and the function `publish()`, and instead of a dedicated view the controller just redirects back to the list view).

For more information on how all the Joomla MVC parts fit together, see [this wiki article](https://docs.joomla.org/Absolute_Basics_of_How_a_Component_Functions).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for details explanation about sub controllers, the docs are really poor and confuse. Which took me long time to understand the concept of Joomla :(.

Comment: It can be a little tricky, but it makes sense soon enough :)

Answer (score 2):

Joomla MVC follows a naming convention to choose the file and class names.

> ```
> This folder holds additional controllers, if needed by the application.
>
>    /site/controllers/{controllername}.php
>    This file holds the controller class {ComponentName}Controller{ControllerName}. This class must extend the base class JController.
> ```

You find more information in Joomla Docs, [here](https://docs.joomla.org/File_Structure_and_Naming_Conventions)

Comment: Hi Anibal, thanks for the answer. But the docs are not clear to me. Suppose I have "/site/controllers/test.php" controller. In "/site/" I have "router.php" & "controller.php", how do I use test.php controller to render the view "test" :) ?

Comment: Joomla MVC has a convention to load certain files and execute classes and function. That's the point of the whole MVC pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If by all controllers you mean everything but controller.php, then placing them in that folder will work just fine. You call a specific controller with the task variable. For instance if you want to call the save method of the employer controller then you set the task to employer.save

I hope this helps. Happy Joomla!ng

Comment: Hi Mathew, thanks for help. It's quite confuse with me, could you send me some demo please??

Comment: You can check how any core controller works, for example com_contact.